# Закрепить верхнюю шапку

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть две секции, которые нужно зафиксировать на вверху страницы, и при прокрутке что бы они оставались вверху.

```
<section class ="grey">
  Тут какой то код
</section>

<section class="mnu_color">
  тут какой то код
</section>
```

Закрепляю вот так

```
.grey {
    position: fixed !important;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    margin-top: 142px;
}

.mnu_color {
    position: fixed !important;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    margin-top: 241px;
}
```

Но на на разных экранах отступы работаю криво, если делать без `margin` то не работает. Если делать только один блок, например, `grey` без `margin`, то работает? Как зафиксировать две секции? Рабочий пример [тут](http://new-live.kz/).

Comment: А почему бы просто не завернуть обе секции в один блок?

Comment: Попробовал, не получилось, сделал div блок, обернул обе секции в него. Присвои свойства вообще все исчесло.

Comment: я бы вообще при скролле сделал бы  блок фиксированный  типа такого : http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/YpmwmW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Положите оба `section` в один `div` (например, с `id` `header`) и установите ему стили

```
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1; /* Любое положительное значение */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

#block1 {
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   background: #f4a;
   height: 80px;
}

#block2 {
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   background: #a4f;
   height: 40px;
   top: 80px;
}

#content { padding-top: 120px }
```

```html
<section id="block1">Section 1</section>
<section id="block2">Section 2</section>
<div id="content">Hello WorldHello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World  </div>
```